# Syntax Highlighter in Haskell

Tags: java, html, haskell, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a Syntax Highlighting for Java in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785171/how-to-make-a-syntax-highlighting-for-java-in-haskell)

I've asked before how to make a syntax highlighter in Haskell for Java language that have the output in HTML. I received few answers, regarding at few libraries. I wasn't able to install and run any of those, so I am forced to ask again.
How can I start making this syntax highlighter in Haskell ? A piece of code or an tutorial will help me a lot more, than mentioning a package. I repeat myself telling that I wasnt able to install and run both illuminate or highlighting-kate.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why didn't illuminate work? What went wrong?

Comment: I always use highlighting-kate. Rather than repeating yourself, perhaps show what error message you had, so others can diagnose.

Comment: This should be closed. You should instead ask for more help using your previous question on the same topic, rather than asking about the same issue again.

Comment: "I wasn't able to install and run any of those" - you should try asking for help on the #haskell irc channel: that is a more appropriate forum for back-and-forth discussion and people there can help make sure you get the packages installed correctly. You are asking a very vague question and it seems that you want us to do all of the work for you. If your problem is that you are new to the Haskell ecosystem, try reading http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program

Answer (score 0):

trifecta can be used to build a highlighter for any grammar you define in it. The default parser captures an interval map of where the tokens were recognized and tags them semantically, and there is a module to take that map and generate a highlighted HTML stream.

I hesitated to recommend this, but mostly because you explicitly asked people not to give you package names. However, I don't see how anyone can help you solve your problem without doing so.